# How to ignore specific elements being added to Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, character

I have a python list. Let's say it's an empty list. Is there any way that I can make the list ignore specifc characters that when someone tries to add, at the time of list creation itself.

Suppose I want to ignore all the '.' characters to be ignored when someone tries to append the character usinng list.append('.').

Is there any way to mention that at the time of list creation itself?

Comment: Who is "someone", why are they appending these unwanted items to the list, and why do you want the list itself to be responsible for ignoring those items?

Comment: Have you tried subclassing `list?

Comment: Someone is none other than me. I have a constraint to have a list which ignores the specified character when appending accidentally or on purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a special appending function which modifies the list in place if the character is not a `'.'`:

```
def append_no_dot(l, c):
   if c != '.': l.append(c)
```

---

```
>>> l = ['a','b']
>>> append_no_dot(l, 'c')
>>> append_no_dot(l, '.')
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should do this, but if you really have to, you could subclass a list like so:

```
class IgnoreList(list):
    def append(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
        if item == '.':
            return
        return super(IgnoreList, self).append(item)
```

But is horribly un-pythonic. A better solution is to just check the value before calling append.

```
if value != '.':
    my_list.append(value)
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this in python would be to create a new class with the desired behaviour

```
>>> class mylist(list):
...     def append(self, x):
...             if x != ".":
...                     super().append(x)
... 
>>> l = mylist()
>>> l.append("foo")
>>> l
['foo']
>>> l.append(".")
>>> l
['foo']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class IgnoreList(list):

    def __init__(self, ignore_me):
        self.ignore_me = ignore_me

    def check(self, v):
        return v == self.ignore_me

    def append(self, v):
        if not self.check(v):
            super(IgnoreList, self).append(v)


my_list = IgnoreList('x')        # `x` to be ignored here
my_list.append('a')
my_list.append('b')
my_list.append('x')
my_list.append('c')
print my_list

######OUTPUT########
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Can we do the same thing in a simple manner. Not too complex and big as you've mentioned above @Vishvajit Pathak

Comment: @SukumarRdjf This is the best approach and it covers other requirements that might be useful to you.